# how to make switch case back to another switch case (C)

Tags: c

I want to make switch case in the switch case and make back switch. if remember we can use if else to make switch case move to the first switch case. thk

this is my current code now thk

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

   int a,b;
    system("cls");
    printf("Cara Membuat daftar Pertanyaan!\n");
    printf("1. Matematika\n");
    printf("2. Bahasa indonesia\n");
    printf("3. Bahasa Inggris\n");
    printf("4. Kewarganegaraan\n");
    printf("0. Exit \n");
    printf("Masukan no dari 1-4 (0) : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    switch(a) 
    {
        case 1 :  system("cls");
                  printf("1. Perkalian\n");
                  printf("2. Pertambahan\n");
                  printf("3. Perkurangan\n");
                  printf("4. Pembagian\n");
                  printf("5. Kembali \n");
                  printf("Masukan no dari 1-5 : ");
                  scanf("%d",&b);
                  if( b == 5)
                  {
                        switch(a);
                    }
                    else {
                            break;
                    }

                  break;
        default : printf("Error");
    }

 return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Put the 'nested' switch into a function of its own and, when you need to,just return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in a `while` loop, and only allow the loop to run for the `Kembali` option. You could also implement this as a recursive function, but that can get complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int loop = 1;

    while (loop) {
        loop = 0;
        system ("cls");

        printf ("Cara Membuat daftar Pertanyaan!\n");
        printf ("1. Matematika\n");
        printf ("2. Bahasa indonesia\n");
        printf ("3. Bahasa Inggris\n");
        printf ("4. Kewarganegaraan\n");
        printf ("0. Exit \n");
        printf ("Masukan no dari 1-4 (0) : ");

        scanf ("%d", &a);

        switch (a) {
            case 0: {
                printf ("Exited\n");
                break;
            }

            case 1: {
                system ("cls");

                printf ("1. Perkalian\n");
                printf ("2. Pertambahan\n");
                printf ("3. Perkurangan\n");
                printf ("4. Pembagian\n");
                printf ("5. Kembali \n");
                printf ("Masukan no dari 1-5 : ");

                scanf ("%d", &b);

                if (b == 5) {
                    loop = 1;
                }

                break;
            }

            default: {
                printf ("Error\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```